# Can't load "sdl2-ttf" or "sdl2-image" with quicklisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to get the program "Sketch" (https://github.com/vydd/sketch) working. It "relies on SDL2 Image and SDL2 TTF", but I can't get them to load with quicklisp. I'm on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 using CCL 1.11

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
To load "sdl2":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    sdl2
; Loading "sdl2"
To load "sdl2-ttf":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    sdl2-ttf
; Loading "sdl2-ttf"
> Error: Unable to load any of the alternatives:
>           ((:FRAMEWORK "SDL2_ttf") (:DEFAULT "libSDL2_ttf"))
> While executing: CFFI::FL-ERROR, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Skip loading "sketch_scratch/scratch.lisp"
> type :? for other options
1 > cffi:*darwin-framework-directories*
((CFFI::EXPLODE-PATH-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLE "DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH") (CFFI::FALLBACK-DARWIN-FRAMEWORK-DIRECTORIES))
1 >
```

Here are some screenshots showing the error, the source code, and that I have copies of the .framework files in both the project directory and my hard_drive/Library/Frameworks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHkfR.jpg

Comment: What is the value of `cffi:*darwin-framework-directories*`? Does it look like it is searching where it should?

Comment: When I tried to get the value of `cffi:*darwin-framework-directories*`, I just got more variable names: http://imgur.com/TZ8Waui

Comment: Can you evaluate `(list (CFFI::EXPLODE-PATH-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLE "DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH") (CFFI::FALLBACK-DARWIN-FRAMEWORK-DIRECTORIES))`?

Comment: `(NIL (#P"/Users/PC/_me/programming/lisp/" #P"/Users/PC/Library/Frameworks/" #P"/Library/Frameworks/" #P"/System/Library/Frameworks/"))`

when I copy the path of the file from Finder I get:
`/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework`

Comment: Thanks for providing details. I can't test on OSX but hopefully someone else will be able to find out what is happening.

Comment: also not on MacOS, but https://discussions.apple.com/message/17063689#message17063689 explains the three flavors of `Library` folders. Seems like `/Library/Frameworks` needs to be added to `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH`?

Comment: Hi there. I actually tried to install sketch and had to install the SDL_image and SDL-TTF libraries, so had a similar dialog as the OP. The install worked - and I must say I am quite impressed with sketch from a quick play - worth the 10 minutes to install ccl! I don't think its DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH that needs to be set. In my install, the libraries went into /opt/local/lib and the build process went on from there. You don't want to mess with any DYLD_ environment variables . From El Capitan onwards you have to disable SIP to set them. Symlink your libraries into /opt/local/lib and try that.

Comment: I got it working using macports lib in /opt/local/lib under OS X 10.10.5 after adding this path to cffi:*foreign-library-directories* as described here: https://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/_002aforeign_002dlibrary_002ddirectories_002a.html